# How to sell shredded plastic in the UK?

Tags: recycling, plastic

I would like to purchase a shredding machine in order to shred plastic myself, I was wondering if there were any standards I'd need to watch out for and where I could find businesses willing to purchase this plastic.

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! Why do you want to shred the plastic? Why not sell it as it is? In any case, making recycling cost-effective is a matter of scale. You need lots of plastic before a business is interested in buying. Also you probably want to separate the [different types of plastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resin_identification_code) so you can offer batches of a particular type

Comment: I assumed more recycling plants and hobbyists would be willing to purchase it if it was processed but that assumption may be wrong. @THelper

Comment: For hobbyist you are probably right, for recycling plants I doubt it. Perhaps if you can guarantee high quality and bulk delivery